# How do I use vector as input buffer for socket in C++

Tags: c++

I normally set up a huge size buffer and read data from socket and I realized that it is not a good way to read data.

I used to have something like this

```
int bufsize = 4096;
char *buf;
int recv = read(sock, buf, bufsize)
```

I liked to use std::vector to replace the char buffer. I am not sure this is the better way though.

Could you please provide me sample tutorials or examples about this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the advantage using string over vector?

Comment: As you know, if the recv data is string, it can useful for manipulating. :) Don't mind this comment.

Comment: @mattn, `std::string` isn't guaranteed to keep its data contiguously so you can't read right in the `std::string`.

Comment: @kirill-v-lyadvinsky But std::string have reserve() too. I guess that it can pass to str.data() for second argument. Of cource, this is talking about "DATA IS STRING. DATA IS NULL TERMINATED". :)

Comment: @mattn: I don't see how this would guarantee anything: `std::string` could still `reserve()` memory in a non-contiguous fashion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's easy:

```
std::vector<char> buf(4096); // create buffer with preallocated size
int recv = read( sock, &buf[0], buf.size() );
```

Comment: What if I set the buffer size as 100 and incoming packet is bigger than that? I

Comment: Also do I flush out the vector after read to get the new data?

Comment: You can use [`std::vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) function to resize the buffer.

Comment: Just to add, Using &buf[0] as a pointer to the underlying array for both reading and writing is safe and guaranteed to work by the C++ standard.